# Установка Драйвера Canon LBP2900 Linux Manjaro

Tags: linux

Не могу установить драйвер на принтер LBP2900. Перерыл весь интернет. Сам в linux новичок. Помогите пожалуйста

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Manjaro это Арч, а LBP2900 это CAPT платформа. По настройке смотри тут https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Canon_CAPT (понадобится [сборка](https://wiki.manjaro.org/index.php/Arch_User_Repository)).

aur/capt-src дикая смесь устаревшего кода, но работает, иногда зависает.

aur/captdriver-git у меня не завелся, может когда-нибудь доведут до ума.

Comment: Большое спасибо, если получиться настроить отпишусь

Comment: Снова привет. Вроде установил принтер, но при попытке распечатать тестовую страницу пишет "Отправка данных на принтер"  и не печатает. Что может быть не так?

Comment: ccpd не запущен